# Kernel panic after upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: bug-reporting

a few hours ago I upgraded my Ubuntu version to 13.04(from 12.10).
Since then,in about 2-3 hours I have 2-3 times Kernel panic-not syncing.
Does anybody has the same issue?How can I resolve this?
I am on a laptop Dell Inspiron.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. Quick fix is to boot with the second line in your grub start screen and select the last installed kernel from 12.10 which works OK on 13.04. On my Dell Laptop that was:

3.5.0-27-generic

I suspect it is an issue with the latest version of the wireless driver

Comment: Yes,I am loading the previous kernel.This works.I am looking forward to seeing a patch for this bug.thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you using tried the [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme)
If you edit your sources to use [saucy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138987) you can get the 3.9.0-1-generic kernel, it is based on the 3.9-rc8 kernel